# what does 'filtered out the window and up and down the street' mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context

what does 'filtered out the window and up and down the street' mean?

> Esmerelda’s loud, derisive laughter, when Blackpool asked her out for
> coffee, filtered out the window and up and down the street.

Does it mean that the laughter was coming from out the window and was heard up and down the street (which, I presume, means on the whole street)?

Sorry, I don't have any context, the sentence is all I got.

Comment: Yes, you've got it exactly. And, for what it's worth, there shouldn't be commas before or after "*when Blackpool asked her out for coffee*".

Comment: It's in -- guess where? -- Harry Potter. _Chamber of Secrets_.

Comment: The windows acted as a filter for her laughter. Generally, that would mean it is not as strong as it would be if you were in the room.

Comment: _Out of the window_ would be better. You _filter out_ unwanted solids from a liquid.

Comment: @gotube Purdue University disagrees with you: *"3. Use a pair of commas in the middle of a sentence to set off clauses, phrases, and words that are not essential to the meaning of the sentence. Use one comma before to indicate the beginning of the pause and one at the end to indicate the end of the pause."*

Comment: @PRL75 Kudos for looking the rule up, but either that definition is wrong, or you're misapplying it. As you're applying that rule, this punctuation is correct: "*I picked up the phone, when it rang*". But it's not correct. The comma is wrong.